# Why is my images not appearing, when trying to get them from database

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

Hiya I am getting information from my database to present onto the webpage, everything is correct with connection as the information is present on the page.

But when it comes to the pictures they come up with a little box of where they are meant to be.
Heres the code I have:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require './db/connect.php';
include './includes/header.php';
?>

<h2>Production</h2>

<?php
if($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Production")){
if($count = $result->num_rows){
      $Image = $rows['Image'];      
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo '<pre>'.'<img class="productionimages" src="path/'.$Image.'" />',' '
                ,$row->ProductionName,' ',$row->ProductionType, '</pre>';
    }
    $result->free();
    }
}
     echo $result; 

include './includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Heres a picture below of what appears on the screen.

[image: Problem I am having]

Comment: right click on those images and check the path, or just look at the generated HTML. Most likely you have an incorrect image path set

Comment: its obviously the path but how would I write it to come from the database as the pictures are already in there? They are a blob type btw

Comment: @Lizzy The HTML call to the images will look on your web server for image files. You'll need to drop the files on the disk somewhere so that they can be found. A common practice is to store the images in a directory and store the path to the images in the DB.

Comment: @BigScar Okies, thanks, how in the database do I store the path and what does the datatype become? currently they are a blob where I have uploaded the pictures into. :)

Comment: @Lizzy You'll want to get your images stored on your web server. Then in the DB store the path to each image as a text string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set $Image within the while loop and $rows['Image'] should be $row->Image, like so.

```
<?php
if($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Production")){
if($count = $result->num_rows){

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $Image = $row->Image;
        echo '<pre>'.'<img class="productionimages" src="path/'.$Image.'" />',' '
                ,$row->ProductionName,' ',$row->ProductionType, '</pre>';
    }
    $result->free();
    }
}
     echo $result; 

include './includes/footer.php';
?>
```